# How to make ng-class true for specific elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to repeat the same svg graphic I have based on some data I am pulling. I want to add an "active" class to specific paths of the SVG using ng-class. I have given each path an ng-class attribute:

```
ng-class="{active: shouldRingFillsBeActive}"
```

In my javascript I loop through all the paths with class "ring-fill" and push them into an array called "rings." Now I would like to give only certain paths the class "active". If I make $scope.shouldRingFillsBeActive to true, then all rings will have the active class. For example: if rings[3] needs the 'active' class how can I make ng-class true just for that one element?

Right now I am using attr but that doesn't work because the view has not been loaded yea. So now I am going to use $scope.

Here's my javascript:

```
for(var i in data) {
        var dataObject = data[i];
        var team = dataObject.team;

        var ringToHighlight = Math.floor((dataObject.average_score/maxScore)*totalRings); //round down

        var i = 0;

        var rings = [];
        var ringClass = 'path[data="overall"].ring-fill.'+team+':not(.ring-border)';
        var ring = $(ringClass);
        console.log(ring);


        ring.each(function(){
            rings.push($(this)[0]);
        });

        rings.reverse();


        while( i < ringToHighlight) {
            fillPath(i);
            i = i + 1;
        }

    }



    function fillPath(i) {
        if(i < ringToHighlight) {
            $scope.shouldRingFillsBeActive = true;
            var selectedRing = $(rings[i]);
            selectedRing.attr("class", "ring-fill active");
        }
    }
```

Comment: looks like you are already doing that with `selectedRing.attr("class", "ring-fill active");`, if you just remove the `ng-class` my guess is it would work. However I would like to add that I hope this is done in a directive and not in a controller?

Comment: @Sonaryr attr doesn't work because it looks for the class "ring-fill" before it has even been made. Thats why I want to use $scope. Is there a way I can make $scope.shouldRingFillsBeActive = true for selected "ring-fills"?

Also why should this be in a directive and not controller?